# Conjugation by elementary matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $ A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} $ be a real matrix, with $c$ not zero. Show that using conjugation by elementary matrices, one can "eliminate" the $a$ entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $c \neq 0$, the elementary matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -a/c \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
corresponds to the row operation $R_1 \gets R_1-\frac{a}{c} R_2$.

We compute
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -a/c \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -a/c \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b-da/c \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -a/c \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b-da/c \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a/c \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b-da/c \\
c & a+d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
which has the desired form.

Or, if we have the $^{-1}$ on the other side:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a/c \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a/c \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -a/c \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a/c \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b-da/c \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a/c \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b-da/c \\
c & a+d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
which has the desired form.

Comment: I think it is $P^{-1}AP$ not $PAP^{-1}$

Comment: Can I ask you another question (it is not included in the problem I was just wondering): If c and a are zero, which matrices are similar to the matrix with the previous condition ?

Comment: It depends on whether $b$ or $d$ are zero.  If $b \neq 0$ and $d \neq 0$, they would be the matrices of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & s \\ 0 & t \end{bmatrix}$$ where $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$.  Here, row operations will preserve the first column of zeroes.  If $b=0$ and $d \neq 0$, they would be matrices of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & s \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & t \end{bmatrix}.$$  Finally, if $b=d=0$ then it'd just be $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Sir This question is form artin , There is extension of this question is that which matrices with c=0 are similar to matrix in which the a entry is 0? I am thinking every such matrix will be similar as we have to just exchange first row and 2nd. Is my interprittion is wrong ? as It seems to me so trivial so I am asking